# как вернуть массив объектов с нужными полями объектов js (name, team,goals)

Tags: javascript

вот код

```
function getGoalsStat(players){
  
  }
  
  // examples
  const players = [
    {
      name: 'Jason Mount',
      birthdate: '19.12.1993',
      country: 'Deutschland',
      number: '21',
      team: 'Manchester United',
      position: 'MF',
      goals: 4,
    },
    {
      name: 'Jason Mount',
      birthdate: '01.01.2001',
      country: 'Deutschland',
      number: '16',
      team: 'Manchester United',
      position: 'MF',
      goals: 0,
    },
    {
      name: 'Finne Bard',
      birthdate: '13.02.1995',
      country: 'Norwegen',
      number: '26',
      position: 'FW',
      team: 'Fulham United',
      goals: 1,
    },
    {
      name: 'Gerhardt Yannick',
      birthdate: '13.03.1994',
      country: 'Deutschland',
      number: 31,
      position: 'MF',
      team: 'Liverpool',
      goals: 8,
    },
  ];
  
console.log(getGoalsStat(players));
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по заголовку, вам нужно из одного массива объектов сделать другой с более ограниченным набором полей. Если я правильно понимаю, можно так:

```js
function getGoalsStat(players){
  return players.map(
    ({ name, team, goals }) => ({ name, team, goals })
  );
}
  
  // examples
  const players = [
    {
      name: 'Jason Mount',
      birthdate: '19.12.1993',
      country: 'Deutschland',
      number: '21',
      team: 'Manchester United',
      position: 'MF',
      goals: 4,
    },
    {
      name: 'Jason Mount',
      birthdate: '01.01.2001',
      country: 'Deutschland',
      number: '16',
      team: 'Manchester United',
      position: 'MF',
      goals: 0,
    },
    {
      name: 'Finne Bard',
      birthdate: '13.02.1995',
      country: 'Norwegen',
      number: '26',
      position: 'FW',
      team: 'Fulham United',
      goals: 1,
    },
    {
      name: 'Gerhardt Yannick',
      birthdate: '13.03.1994',
      country: 'Deutschland',
      number: 31,
      position: 'MF',
      team: 'Liverpool',
      goals: 8,
    },
  ];
  
console.log(getGoalsStat(players));
```

Если нет, приведите пример желаемого результата.